# Embed OneNote in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-onenote

I know it is possible to embed an Excel sheet into OneNote... but is the reverse possible?

My end goal would be to have a OneNote page directly in my worksheet, so the user can write in OneNote from Excel, complete with the OneNote functionalities. I'm not talking about a hyperlink to OneNote, I can already do that. I really mean an embedded version (think about a textbox with OneNote-like functionalities). I haven't been able to find anything on that subject on Msdn, since everything I find is about the opposite situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible. OneNote is not a "file format" that you can embed in another Office application.

Embedding Word or Excel files into OneNote is possible because OneNote is great at managing the underlying XML that makes up Excel or Word files. A OneNote "file" is basically a folder on steroids, into which you can throw all kinds of things: pictures, text, Word, Excel files.